# Rdocumentation is behind in base package

Tags: r, documentation

I see that base package in Rdocumentation site is 3.6.2 but in Rdrr it is 4.1.3.

Anyone knows why?

Should I stick to Rdrr?

Comment: This really isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. These are both third party websites which choose to host information not related to the official R project. Feel free to choose which ever gives you the information you need. Stack Overflow is not a recommendation site for other websites.

Comment: @MrFlick , shall I remove my comment then? It was not about asking a recommendation. Mostly if the second is updated and the first is outdated. Then, I should not use th first one because of misleading information.